# What does this power adapter symbol mean?

Tags: laptop, ground

I have a laptop power brick with this symbol on it.

[image: Unknown symbol]

It reminds me of a Class II symbol:

[image: Class II symbol]

but is, obviously, different.

The central symbol looks like a noiseless (clean) earth (ground) symbol (see [here](http://www.tciaffairs.net/electrical-grounding-schematic/schematics-use-of-ground-symbols-in-circuit-diagrams-regarding-electrical-grounding-schematic/)):

[image: Noiseless (clean) earth (ground) symbol]

It's unclear what the two symbols might mean if they're nested.

Answer (score 2):

This is symbol "IEC 60417-6092" and is used on equipment having a power supply cord where a conductor with green-and-yellow insulation is used only to provide a FUNCTIONAL EARTHING connection. Source: UL 60950-1 2nd ed. That means that accessible metal parts, outputs, etc. are double or reinforced insulated from mains, but can be connected to earth terminal via power cord for a "functional" reason - Can be electromagnetic compliance, filtering noise, getting rid of static or anything else not related to electrical safety.

Answer (score 0):

This is symbol is meant to "identify a piece of class II equipment with the functional earthing (grounding)." ([Source](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:6092))

[image: Class II equipment with functional grounding]

Answer (score -2):

Function/description :
To identify a noiseless (clean) earth (ground) terminal, e.g. of a specially designed earthing (grounding) system to avoid causing malfunction of the equipment
https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:5018-1977

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer the question since it does not address the meaning of the symbol I asked about, but, rather, repeats information already included in the question concerning one of the component symbols.